# Is there a good reference for how ribbon structures change when one switches coproducts?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, r-matrix, ribbon-hopf-algebras

I'm just going assume readers are familiar with the notions of R-matrix and ribbon categories.

Given a quasi-triangular Hopf algebra $A$ with $R$-matrix $R$, one can construct the co-opposite Hopf algebra with the same multiplication, but the factors switched in the coproduct $\Delta$, and the antipode inverted.  Both $R^{21}$ (switched factors) and $R^{-1}$ are $R$-matrix for this new coproduct.

> Now, let $v$ be a ribbon element for $(A,R)$.  Is $v^{-1}$ a ribbon element for $(A^{op},R^{21})$?

Checking a few examples suggests this is so, and I'm sure I could check it relatively easily.  Is there anywhere I can reference?

Comment: It's surely just a short, direct calculation, so I don't know that it's even worth a reference.